# Hbm2ddl update dosen't remove constraint

Tags: mysql, hibernate

As we know the hbm2ddl  hibernate update operation never remove column or constraint or change a column dataType , is there any way to make this possible ?? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I basically see three different approaches.

1. Use a database migration tool like Flyway or Liquibase to manage your database structure and do not use Hibernates internal mechanism
2. Write your own database migration tool (not recommended)
3. Set `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` to `create` to re-create the schema every time (with the disadvantage that you lose your data).

I personally always recommend using a "professional" database migration tool when migrations become necessary and only use Hibernates built-in mechanisms for Demo projects or small proof of concepts because tools like the mentioned Flyway or Liquibase store database migrations in files that can be versioned making past migrations transparent and reproducable.

Comment: I don't quite understand - of course you must execute the scripts. Either manually or via e. g. a Maven task but Flyway or Liquibase are not standalone programs that work "out of the box" magically on your database. A common use-case is having all migrations stored as (a list of ) files and then execute them on "Installing" your software.